# Finding Look alike customers

Tags: clustering, similarity, metric

I have a set of customers and their attributes (say spend/balance/etc.) per month.
At month X something happen for some customers, but not all (call this set A).
So, now I want to find customers who are like customers in A, but not in A, before month X, i.e. have similar spend/balance/etc. and then see if not going through the same event at month X made them behave differently from customers in A.

How do I do this using python? Do I just take all customers in A and for each of them I define a metric and see who is the closest (most similar) customer and I repeat that for each customer in A? Is there a better way? Is there any library in python (in scikit-learn, for example) that has this already implemented?